# c# amazon AWS s3: Any way to upload user browsed images directly to s3 without downloading it on our local servers?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have a website where users upload their product images. We have given user browse option to pick images from their local system. Currently:

1. Once the user clicks on browser button, and select some local image for uploading, we save the user browsed image to some location on our server.
2. We show a thumbnail of the image to the user.
3. In the background, we pass our server image path to s3 and get back the s3 path of the same image.

What we want to achieve is, we don't want to save the image on our server in the 1st step as we have created piles of images by saving it on our server.

Is there any way where we could upload image to s3 without saving the image on our server? Though we want to display the thumbnail of the uploaded image.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly upload the images to AWS S3 from your Client's browser without saving in your server and its one of the main use cases of S3. Have a look at [AWS S3 JavaScript SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html) for more details.

You might need to store the file names, for querying in your server database or similar but not the image itself. Apart from that, if you plan to allow only authorized parties to upload images from their Web Browser. Go through the [AWS S3 Signed URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html) section for more details.

Also you can do the thumbnail creation using AWS Lambda, S3 trigger where, thumbnail creation happens automatically when, the user uploads an image.